# Wysiwyg подружить с div contenteditable

Tags: wysiwyg, javascript, contenteditable

Нужен wysiwyg, который бы основывался не на фрейме, а на div с contenteditable=’true’. Перелопатил весь инет, не нашел ничего похожего. Решил писать сам. Конечно, с execCommand проблем не было, но что делать там, где функционал execCommand заканчивается? Например для вставки атрибута target в ссылку? Короче говоря:

1. Как сохранить выделение текста в div, при клике вне области div?
2. Нашёл классную статью на хабре - http://habrahabr.ru/post/38077/ Но не могу переделать программу под div. Подскажите, в каких строках копать хоть?

Да, ModaL, здесь таким вопросом задавался, но ответов я там не нашёл.

Comment: пример кода где у вас что-то не получается и что-то получается покажите. в свое время @modal много каких вопросов задал на эту тему и большая часть была отвечена. так-что попробуйте и вы задать корректный вопрос. то что описано на хабре без iframe работать не будет.

Comment: Плюнул на div и начал писать через iframe. Но стало гораздо труднее добраться до элементов фрейма. Надо что бы при клике на img внутри фрейма срабатывала функция. Исправьте, почему такой подход не работает?

window.onload = function()
{frames['hidden_pole'].document.body.getElementsByTagName('IMG').onclick = function(){alert ('It works');}}

Ещё проблема. Контент фрейма на новую строку не перенесётся, если scrolling='auto' (или yes). Т.е. когда заканчивается место, появляется полоса прокрутки. Если убрать скроллинг - то текст переносится. Но как быть с вертикальным скроллингом, он то нужен?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9u4FV/ насчет поведения окна iframe - не подскажу, не делал сам редакторы, т.к. велопромышленность обойдется и без меня.

Comment: И на том спасибо!)

Comment: Вопрос про контейнер ещё в силе...

Контент фрейма на новую строку не перенесётся, если scrolling='auto' (или yes). Т.е. когда заканчивается место, появляется полоса прокрутки. Если убрать скроллинг - то текст переносится. Но как быть с вертикальным скроллингом, он то нужен?

Comment: в этом проблема что-ли ? http://jsfiddle.net/9u4FV/2/

Comment: Как я понимаю, проблему должен решить стиль overflowx (iframeDocument.body.style.overflowX="auto";)? Что-то не работает.

У меня фрейм задается так: 
var iframe = "<iframe id='hidden_pole' style='' src=\"javascript: document.open(); document.domain='" +
 document.domain + "'; document.close();\" frameborder='0'></iframe>";

Т.е. если я даже вручную у body такой стиль пропишу - не работает.

Основу я на хабре взял, ссылка в самом первом вопросе. К сожалению, не хватает символов, что быть кинуть код.